# MDX Calculated member in WHERE clause causes different results

Tags: ssas, mdx

The following query has different result sets depending on which of the [Measures] I use in the WHERE clause.
Having the [Measures].[MetricFormula] instead of [Measures].[Actual] activated, the query delivers a different (and expected) result.

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[MetricFormula] AS Measures.[Downloads]
MEMBER [Measures].[Actual] AS [Measures].[MetricFormula], LANGUAGE = 1031,FORMAT_STRING='#,##0'

SET [mySet] as 
topcount(
    nonempty(
        filter(
            distinct descendants({[AppPackages].[AppPackages].&[F_TAAM00000069]}), 
            [Measures].[MetricFormula] <> 0 AND ([AppPackages].[AppPackages].PROPERTIES('AppTypeID') = 'DETAIL')
            ),
        [Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00]:[Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-31T00:00:00]
        )
    ,6
    ,aggregate([Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00]:[Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-31T00:00:00], [Measures].[MetricFormula]))


select
([Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00]:[Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-31T00:00:00]) ON COLUMNS,
([mySet]) ON ROWS   

FROM [Facts] 
WHERE (
--([Measures].[MetricFormula]),
([Measures].[Actual]),
{[DownloadTypes].[DownloadTypes].&[New]}
)
```

([Measures].[Downloads] is the real measure defined in the cube.)

Question: Why does it deliver different results?
I use this construct (in various forms) to simplify code based query generation.
I'd like to understand the differnces before I start reworking my query generator.

Background:
The query is supposed to calculate the Top 6 descendants of a given AppPackage for a given time range, based on the given measure. I start by finding the (non empty) descendants for the time range, on which I add the topcount, making sure that the time aggregated measure value drives the top calculation. Finally I put the evaluated set on the rows, the time on columns, specifying by where what to see. It works out nicely, besides the described effect.

Comment: interesting question - I'll test against AdvWks. If you simplify the set does it still behave the same?

Comment: good point. I removed the topcount and kept everything else (nonempty(filter(..)) => the set does NOT change. Hm ... something to think about ...

Comment: Is `Measures.[Downloads]` coming directly from RDBMS? If yes, what is the datatype of that column? If not, how are you creating this measure in cube?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti: yes, it comes from RDBMS, teh type in the Cube is currency.

Comment: @whytheq: I just tested with a simple(r) topcount: the problem persists => I will look on what the topcount is doing.

Comment: I stripped it down to the aggregate function in the topcount, but still I don't understand it. I.e. using the topcount(<set>,6,aggregate(<time>,<measure>)) the effect remains, but topcount(<set>,6,<measure>) is "stable" - but doesn't deliver the wanted result (as I want to take only into account the given data range).

Comment: Are you talking about the `WHERE` clause part that changing the measure in there changes the output? Or you talking about replacing every instance of the first measure with second measure throughout the query?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti check out the measures that are in the WHERE clause... ([Measures].[MetricFormula]) / ([Measures].[Actual]) ...they both come from the WITH clause, and they both should be the same!!: so why would swapping from one to the other change the result of this script?

Comment: You are forgetting the `FORMAT_STRING` that you have..Potentially it *can* change value

Comment: @tlow do you agree with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had fun replicating in `AdvWrks` but here it is:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[x] AS 
    [Measures].[Internet Order Count] 
  MEMBER [Measures].[y] AS 
    [Measures].[x] 
   ,LANGUAGE = 1031 
   ,FORMAT_STRING = '#,##0' 
  SET [s] AS 
    TopCount
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        Filter
        (
          [State-Province].[State-Province].MEMBERS
         ,
          [Measures].[x] <> 0
        )
       ,
          [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2005]&[10]
        : 
          [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[5]
      )
     ,10
     ,Aggregate
      (
          [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2005]&[10]
        : 
          [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[5]
       ,[Measures].[x]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2005]&[10]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[5]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,Order
  (
    [s]
   ,[State-Province].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
   ,basc
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  (
    //([Measures].[x]),
    ([Measures].[y]),
   {[Product].[Product Categories].[Category].&[1]}
  );
```

It does the same as your script - if we change to `[x]` then South Australia disappears from the result set.

---

Edit
As to **why** - I now know!

`MDX` is being very kind to you and not erroring even though there is an error in the script:

```
Aggregate
      (
          [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2005]&[10]
        : 
          [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[5]
       ,[Measures].[x]  //<<this is not allowed so `mdx` is ignoring it!
      )
```

So try the following OR try swapping `Aggregate` to `Sum`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MetricFormula] AS 
    Measures.[Downloads] 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Actual] AS 
    [Measures].[MetricFormula] 
   ,LANGUAGE = 1031 
   ,FORMAT_STRING = '#,##0' 
  SET [mySet] AS 
    TopCount
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        Filter
        (
          (DISTINCT 
            Descendants({[AppPackages].[AppPackages].&[F_TAAM00000069]}))
         ,
            [Measures].[MetricFormula] <> 0
          AND 
            [AppPackages].[AppPackages].Properties('AppTypeID') = 'DETAIL'
        )
       ,
          [Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00]
        : 
          [Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-31T00:00:00]
      )
     ,6
     ,Aggregate
      (
          [Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00]
        : 
          [Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-31T00:00:00]
       ,Measures.[Downloads]   //<<<<<<<<<<<<moved away from using a calculated measure as they are not working as expected inside the function `AGGREGATE`
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
    [Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-22T00:00:00]
  : 
    [Time].[Calendar].[Date].&[2015-03-31T00:00:00] ON COLUMNS
 ,[mySet] ON ROWS
FROM [Facts]
WHERE 
  (
    --([Measures].[MetricFormula]),
    [Measures].[Actual]
   ,{[DownloadTypes].[DownloadTypes].&[New]}
  );
```

**WHY?**

Well using the custom measure `[Measures].[MetricFormula]` inside the Aggregate function seems to be illegal, but when you do this as part of the second argument in `TopCount` mdx just ignores the error and uses whatever the default measure is in your cube .... very kind of the engine to ignore that error?!

---

EXAMPLE OF THE ERROR THROWN WHEN FEEDING A CALCULATED MEMBER INTO THE AGGREGATE FUNCTION:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[j] AS 
    [Measures].[Internet Order Count] 
  MEMBER [Measures].[x] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2005]&[10]
      : 
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2006]&[5]
     ,[Measures].[j]   //<<FEEDING "ILLEGAL" CALCULATED MEMBER INTO AGGREGATE FUNCTION
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[x]} ON COLUMNS
 ,[State-Province].[State-Province].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Why is that illegal, dear friend?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti ?? Try it yourself ... I'll add a script for you now - you need to ask Microsoft why.

Comment: Oh yes. Calculated members are not allowed inside aggregate function. Sorry, I didn't read the last part of your answer. I would say great investigation by you.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti dangerous point of this is that if you use Aggregate(<Set>, calculated_Measure) as he 3rd argument of TopCount then it does not throw an erro but just ignores the calculated_Measure ... seems like a bug to me